# iOS 9 UISegmentedControl with vector image stretched

Tags: ios9, photoshop, uisegmentedcontrol, vector-graphics, asset-catalog

My app has a number of buttons in its navigation bar. These are all UISegmentedControls with one segment, wrapped in UIBarButtonItems. Some of them have images that I add through my project's asset catalog, and these all have a width of 50.

I'm using Photoshop to create my button images, and saving them as PDFs so I can use them as vector images in Xcode. The icons themselves are 30x20.

The problem is, the image appears slightly off. There are several small boxes with 1px borders, and they look stretched vertically. I've tried what I think is every combination of width (between 30 and 50) and height (between 20 and 44), including square (30x30, 36x36, etc) and 2:1 (50x25, 48x24, 40x20, etc) and all kinds of odd dimensions, and nothing seems to be just right. I also tried doubling the dimensions, but the image just gets much more vertically compressed.

My question is: what is the exact resolution to have my .psd file so that the vector doesn't appear stretched in some way? It looks equally bad in my Asset Catalog, on the iPad Pro, and on the iPhone 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to set a margin around your image when you are setting the image :

```
yourSegmentedControl.setImage(yourImage.resizableImage(withCapInsets: .init(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10), resizingMode: .stretch), forSegmentAt: 0)
```

You can change the values of "top", "left", "bottom" and "right" as you want.
In that way you can set each image section as you want. This worked for me, I hope it will help!